# For all $a, b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, show $a +b$ is a factor of $a^{2n} - b^{2n}$.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Given solution approach for first problem below, unable to approach the second one.
#1. For all $a, b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, show $a - b$ is a factor of $a^n - b^n$.
By weak form of induction.
Base step: $n=1$.
Hypothesis step: Let, $n=k$; then:
$(a-b) \mid (a^k - b^k)$.
Inductive step: $n=k+1$, 
$a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}=a^k(a-b)+(a^k-b^k)b$
Have two terms both divisible by $a-b$.

#2. For all $a, b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$
, show $a + b$ is a factor of $a^{2n} - b^{2n}$.
By weak form of induction.
Base step: $k=1$.
$(a+b) \mid  (a^2 - b^2) = (a+b)\mid (a-b)(a+b)$
Hypothesis step: Let, $k=2n, n \in\mathbb{Z}$; then:
$(a+b) \mid (a^{2n} - b^{2n})$.
Inductive step: $k+1=2(n+1)$, 
$a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}=a^{2(n+1)} - b^{2(n+1)} = a^{2n}.a^2 - b^{2n}.b^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment:

You can get Heropup's result by applying the induction step you did in 1) twice. Note that $$\begin{aligned}
a^{2(n + 1)} - b^{2(n + 1)} &= a^{2n + 1}(a - b) + (a^{2n + 1} - b^{2n + 1})b \\
&= a^{2n + 1}(a - b) + (a^{2n}(a - b) + (a^{2n} - b^{2n})b)b
\end{aligned}
$$ Which after simplifying gives

$$
a^{2(n + 1)} - b^{2(n + 1)} = a^{2n + 1}(a - b) + a^{2n}(a - b)b + (a^{2n} - b^{2n})b^2 
$$

The right term $(a^{2n} - b^{2n})b^2$ is divisible by $a + b$ by the induction hypothesis on $a^{2n} - b^{2n}$. For the remaining terms, note that $$
a^{2n + 1}(a - b) + a^{2n}(a-b)b = (a - b)(a^{2n + 1} + a^{2n}b) = (a + b)(a - b)a^{2n},
$$ hence they are also divisible by $a + b$, thus $a^{2(n + 1)} - b^{2(n + 1)}$ is divisible by $a + b$.

Comment: Can there be a logic too for this part, seems need go into combinatorics then; an altogether different question?

Comment: The logic I used for trying this is that since you have a result for reducing $a^{k + 1} - b^{k + 1}$ to something involving $a^k - b^k$, you can reduce $a^{2(n + 1)} - b^{2(n + 1)} = a^{2n + 2} - b^{2n + 2}$ to something involving $a^{2n} - b^{2n}$ by doing this twice. This is not guaranteed to work, but the general idea here is that if you don't have an idea how to start a problem but you have a result you can apply, it is always a good idea to try it and see how it goes.

Comment: In this case it worked out, in other cases it could be that the resulting expression is too complex and it would be less work to try to find something else.

Comment: Because the statement $(a + b) \mid a^k - b^k$ is only true for even $k$. For example, if $a = 3$, $b = 2$ and $k = 3$ then $a + b = 5$ but $a^k - b^k = 27 - 8 = 19$ which is not divisible by $5$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, a single case by contradiction helps to show.

Comment: Kindly see my comment to @David's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The inductive step is similar to the first problem you did.  Observe
$$(a^{2k} - b^{2k})b^2 = a^{2k} b^2 - b^{2k+2},$$ so
$$(a^{2k} - b^{2k})b^2 + a^{2k+2} - a^{2k} b^2 = a^{2k+2} - b^{2k+2}.$$  Therefore
$$a^{2k+2} - b^{2k+2} = (a^{2k} - b^{2k})b^2 + (a^2 - b^2) a^{2k}.$$

Then by the induction hypothesis, $a+b \mid a^{2k} - b^{2k}$ and we already know $a + b \mid a^2 - b^2$; therefore, $a + b \mid a^{2k+2} - b^{2k+2}$.

---

If one studies the argument used in the first result, the above computation should be quite natural and does not need to be motivated by repeated induction or more complicated algebra.

In the first result, the inductive step employs the identity $$a^{k+1} - b^{k+1} = a^k (a-b) + (a^k - b^k) b.$$  This takes the $n = k$ case, $a^k - b^k$, multiplies it by $b$ to get $a^k b - b^{k+1}$.  This gives us the $-b^{k+1}$ that we want for the case $n = k+1$, but it is missing $a^{k+1}$ and has an extra $a^k b$; hence the addition of the term $a^k (a-b)$ on the right-hand side.

**We do almost exactly the same thing** for the second result.  We want to prove the case $n = 2(k+1)$ from the case $n = 2k$, so it is completely natural to take $a^{2k} - b^{2k}$, multiply it by $b^2$ to get $a^{2k}b^2 - b^{2k+2}$, and then note that we need to add $a^{2k+2}$ and subtract $a^{2k}b^2$.  That is all that that is being done in the first part of this answer, and yields a **completely analogous identity** as in the first result.

For this reason, it is completely perplexing to me how anyone could understand the first result yet fail to comprehend the second.  All we are doing here is establishing a simple algebraic identity.  The identity that was used to show the first result was simply asserted out of nowhere; we could do the same for the analogous identity for the second result.

Comment: Also worth nothing perhaps (for OP) is that you can also get this by applying the induction step in 1) twice.

Comment: @Rushy please elaborate, as still am unable to understand this answer

Comment: @jiten I posted a clarification as an answer (it was too long for a comment). If this makes it understandable, I suggest you accept the answer above as it is the same idea and it was posted first.

Comment: @Rushy had I been so adept, then would have selected even the one posted by big_GolfUniformIndia.

Comment: Might be at that point confused, now obvious that your approach works easily.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=x^{2n}-b^{2n}.$
Since $f(\pm b)=0, \ x\mp b \text{ divides } f(x) \text{ in }\mathbb{Z}[x].$
Therefore, $a\pm b \text{ divides } f(a).$

Comment: Seems the logic for finding zero work, but can you use it to show only for even powers of $a,b$, does $a+b$ divide $a^{2n} - b^{2n}$. I mean using the same method, and not just a counterexample for showing that ($(a+b)\nmid a^n-b^n, n$ being odd integer.

Comment: @jiten If $n$ is odd, then you have that $f(x) = x^n - b^n$ satisfies $f(b) = 0$, so $x - b$ divides $f(x)$ i.e. $a - b$ divides $f(b)$. However due to $n$ being odd, $f(-b) = -2b^n$, so $(x + b)$ is a factor of $f(x)$ only when $b = 0$ in that case. For $b = 0$ of course both $a + b$ and $a - b$ trivially divide $a^n - b^n$ for any $n$.

Comment: Correction to my comment: the statement in the first line should be $a - b$ divides $f(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $a^{2n} - b^{2n}$ as
$$
a^{2n} - b^{2n} = (a^n - b^n)(a^n+b^n).
$$

Using the result you proved (#$1$), $(a+b)$ divides  $a^{2n} - b^{2n}$.

Comment: But, $a^{2n}.a^2 - b^{2n}.b^2$ does not help as it is $\ne (a^n-b^n)(a^n +b^n)(a^2-b^2)$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. So, you want some proof using directly induction? I think that, on this problem, the idea is to use #$1$ to prove #$2$. The induction is used to prove that there is a $(a+b)$ factor on $(a^n - b^n)$

Comment: How does #1 have anything to do with #2?  The first result says $a-b$ divides $a^n - b^n$.  How do you use this to conclude $a+b$ divides $a^{2n} - b^{2n}$?

Comment: One could always argue that viewing $a$ as an indeterminate $a - b$ divides $a^{2n} - b^{2n}$ means $b$ is a root of $f(a) = a^{2n} - b^{2n}$ and since $f(b) = f(-b)$ so is $-b$, although I doubt that's the point of this exercise.

Comment: @Rushy please make an answer.